# How can i build my web app using java 17 and maven correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Am new to java 17 and i tried building my project with java 17 and am getting the below errors how can i fix it.

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) [Guice/NullInjectedIntoNonNullable]: null returned by binding at LocatorWiring
 but the 1st parameter of DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.<init>(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:66) is not @Nullable
  at LocatorWiring
  at DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.<init>(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:66)
      \_ for 1st parameter
  at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1, parent: ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2a139a55]
      \_ installed by: WireModule -> PlexusBindingModule
  while locating DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering
  while locating Object annotated with *
  while locating ResourcesMojo

Learn more:
  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/NULL_INJECTED_INTO_NON_NULLABLE

1 error

======================
Full classname legend:
======================
ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader:    "jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader"
DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering: "org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering"
LocatorWiring:                  "org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring"
PlexusBindingModule:            "org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule"
ResourcesMojo:                  "org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo"
WireModule:                     "org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule"
========================
End of classname legend:
========================
```

also here is what my pom looks like

```xml
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-openfeign -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2022.0.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
<!--            <scope>import</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.openfeign/feign-httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>12.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.00</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version> <!-- Make sure this version is compatible -->
            </plugin>
            <!-- Other plugins -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

i have tried to change from different maven versions still didnt work.

Comment: Remove the jacoco-maven-plugin from your dependencies... also you seemed to be mixing different versions of spring boot ...for example `feign`... there is by default on in spring boot... also hibernate-validator etc. are part of spring boot...  apart from that please post the full pom files not only excerpts... or even better a link to the project...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the error is arising from an incompatibility with Java 17 and the Maven resources plugin you're using.

Java 17 introduced strong encapsulation of the JDK's internal APIs using JEP 396. Some libraries and plugins, which relied on these internal APIs in the past, might fail under Java 17 if they haven't been updated.

Here are some steps to address the issue:

1. Update Maven: Ensure that you're using the latest version of Maven that supports Java 17. Ideally, Maven 3.8.4 or later.
2. Update Maven Resource Plugin: The version 3.3.1 of the maven-resources-plugin that you're using might not be fully compatible with Java 17. Update it to a more recent version that has support for Java 17.
   Replace it with : 3.3.0

After checking these If you still encounter issues, consider creating a specific Maven profile for Java 17. This way, you can have specific plugin configurations and dependencies that are activated only when building with Java 17.

Comment: Wow this was so helpful thank you so much it worked